# How to create alert dialog with image and scrolling [ANDROID]

Tags: java, android, xml, scroll, android-alertdialog

Dialog Java Code:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
                dialog.setTitle("Title...");
                ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView(context);
                scroll.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.transparent);
                scroll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                                             LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));    
                // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
                TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
                text.setText("Android custom dialog example!");
                ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
                dialog.show();
```

XML Code Here:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/layout_root"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:padding="10dp"
          android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">
          >
<ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
           />
<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:textColor="#FFF"
          />
```

I know that if i have only text on alert dialog it's automatically scrolling, but with an imageview automatically scrolling doesn't work.
How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your layout inside a ScrollView:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

      <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/layout_root"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="10dp"
          android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" >

          <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

          <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:textColor="#FFF" />

    </LinearLayout>

<ScrollView>
```

I see that your `LinearLayout` has a `horizontal` orientation. So if this the case and you want to scroll horizontaly, you should replace `ScrollView` by `HorizontalScrollView` and set the orientation to horizontal.
Let me know if this works.